# fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I'm having an error while running `yarn test` on react native mobile application.

```
 Test suite failed to run

    Invariant Violation: __fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set, cannot invoke native modules

      2 | // import console = require('console');
      3 |
    > 4 | if (!NativeModules.DeviceMotionModule) {
        |      ^
      5 |   throw new Error('Native modules for sensors not available. Did react-native link run successfully?')
      6 | }
      7 |

      at invariant (node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:40:15)
      at Object.invariant (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:162:3)
      at Object.require [as NativeModules] (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js:322:12)
      at Object.NativeModules (src/NativeModules/SensorsIOS/sensors.js:4:6)
```

I'm new to testing with jest.

I have a set of costum native modules for IOS and Android in my project (not an npm module).

Comment: I'm having this issue as well, looks like it's been discussed on Expo forums with no resolution, and may be related to the use of React Native components, like TextInput: https://forums.expo.io/t/fbbatchedbridgeconfig-is-not-set-cannot-invoke-native-modules/33053